# Trouble with left joining tables pandas (ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns.)

Tags: python, sql, excel, oracle, pandas

I have two lists where I want to left join one.

This is how I generate the first list:

```
# NB Oracle connection
first_list = pd.read_sql('SELECT firstname, lpad(identifier, 4, 0) from table1', con=Connection)
```

Second list:

```
second_list = pd_read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', converters={'identifier': str})
```

A little bit simplified: The first list looks like this:

```
   name  identifier
0  Firstname     1201
1  Secondname       0
2  Thirdname     1855
3  Fourthname    3333
4  Fifthname     1414
```

The Second list looks like this:

```
   identifier    BIC          BANK
0  0             UNKNOWN      Unknown
1  1201          DNBANKNOKK   DNB Bank ASA 
2  1855          EIDSNO21     Eidsberg Sparebank
3  3333          RYGSNO21     Sparebank1 Østfold Akershus
4  1414          LOSKNO21     Sparebank 1 Lom og Sjåk
```

I want a final list to look like this:

```
   name          identifier  BIC          BANK
0  Firstname     1201        DNBANKNOKK   DNB Bank ASA
1  Secondname       0        UNKNOWN      Unknown
2  Thirdname     1855        EIDSNO21     Eidsberg Sparebank
3  Fourthname    3333        RYGSNO21     Sparebank1 Østfold Akershus
4  Fifthname     1414        LOSKNO21     Sparebank 1 Lom og Sjåk
```

But, When I try to genearte the final list:

```
final_list = first_list.join(second_list, on='identifier', how='left')
```

I get the following error: ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

I get the same error when I try this:

```
first_list['identifier'] = first_list['identifier'].astype(str)
second_list['identifier'] = second_list['identifier'].astype(str)
final_list = first_list.join(second_list, on='identifier', how='left')
```

Running dtypes returns both list identifiers as object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how='left'`:

```
final_list = pd.merge(first_list, second_list, on='identifier', how='left')

print(final_list)
         name  identifier         BIC                         BANK
0   Firstname        1201  DNBANKNOKK                 DNB Bank ASA
1  Secondname           0     UNKNOWN                      Unknown
2   Thirdname        1855    EIDSNO21           Eidsberg Sparebank
3  Fourthname        3333    RYGSNO21  Sparebank1 Østfold Akershus
4   Fifthname        1414    LOSKNO21      Sparebank 1 Lom og Sjåk
```

A good an extensive explenation about `merging` in `pandas` can be found here:
[Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Thanks, using merge with left join solved the problem :) I guess merge is "better" than join. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

try like below use `merge`

```
import pandas as pd

final_list = pd.merge(first_list, second_list, how='outer',left_on=['identifier'], right_on=['identifier'])
```