# Trouble with df.join(): ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

> None of these questions adress the issue: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278728/trouble-with-left-joining-tables-pandas-valueerror-you-are-trying-to-merge-on) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) nor could I find the answer in pandas documentation.

Hello, I am trying to find the underlying cause for this error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns.
```

I know I can work around this problem using pandas `concat` or `merge` function, but I am trying to understand the cause for the error. The question is: Why do I get this `ValueError`?

Here's the output of the `head(5)` and `info()` on both dataframes that are used.

`print(the_big_df.head(5))` Output:

```
  account  apt  apt_p  balance       date  day    flag  month  reps     reqid  year
0  AA0420    0    0.0  -578.30 2019-03-01    1       1      3    10  82f2d761  2019
1  AA0420    0    0.1  -578.30 2019-03-02    2       1      3    10  82f2d761  2019
2  AA0420    0    0.1  -578.30 2019-03-03    3       1      3    10  82f2d761  2019
3  AA0421    0    0.1  -607.30 2019-03-04    4       1      3    10  82f2d761  2019
4  AA0421    0    0.1  -610.21 2019-03-05    5       1      3    10  82f2d761  2019
```

`print(the_big_df.info())` Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 36054 entries, 0 to 36053
Data columns (total 11 columns):
account        36054 non-null object
apt            36054 non-null int64
apt_p          36054 non-null float64
balance        36054 non-null float64
date           36054 non-null datetime64[ns]
day            36054 non-null int64
flag           36054 non-null int64
month          36054 non-null int64
reps           36054 non-null int32
reqid          36054 non-null object
year           36054 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), int32(1), int64(5), object(2)
memory usage: 3.2+ MB
```

Here's the dataframe I'm passing to the `join()`; `print(df_to_join.head(5))`:

```
      reqid     id
0  54580f39  13301
1  3ba905c0  77114
2  5f2d80da  13302
3  a1478e98  77115
4  9b09854b  78598
```

`print(df_to_join.info())` Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14332 entries, 0 to 14331
Data columns (total 2 columns):
reqid    14332 non-null object
dni      14332 non-null object
```

The exact next line after the 4 prints stated above is:

```
the_max_df = the_big_df.join(df_to_join,on='reqid')
```

And the output is, as stated above:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Why does this happen, when before it is clearly stated that column `reqid` is an object in both dataframes? Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem here is a **misconception of how join works**: when you say `the_big_df.join(df_to_join,on='reqid')` it *does not mean* join on `the_big_df.reqid == df_to_join.reqid` as one would assume at first glance, but rather join on `the_big_df.reqid == df_to_join.index`. As `requid` is of type `object` and the index is of type `int64` you get the error.

See the [docs for **`join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

> Join columns with other DataFrame either on index or on a key column.
>   ...
>   **on** : str, list of str, or array-like, optional
>   Column or index level name(s) in the caller to join on the index in other, otherwise joins index-on-index.

Look at the following example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1': [1, 2], 'val1': [11,12]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id2': [3, 4], 'val2': [21,22]})
print(df1)
#   id1  val1
#0    1    11
#1    2    12
print(df2)
#   id2  val2
#0    3    21
#1    4    22

# join on df1.id1 (int64) == df2.index (int64) 
print(df1.join(df2, on='id1'))
#   id1  val1  id2  val2
#0    1    11  4.0  22.0
#1    2    12  NaN   NaN

# now df3 same as df1 but id3 as object:
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id3': ['1', '2'], 'val1': [11,12]})

# try to join on df3.id3 (object) == df2.index (int64) 
df3.join(df2, on='id3')
#ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

---

Please note: the above is for a modern versions of pandas. Version 20.3 gave the following result:

```
>>> df3.join(df2, on='id3')
  id3  val1  id2  val2
0   1    11  NaN   NaN
1   2    12  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that this is not a join operation like SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.merge`.

See the [docs for merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wrote in the question that I know I could solve it with merge, but wanted to understand the problem I was facing using `.join()`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you astype(str) to both reqid columns and see if it's still an issue.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow! They *should* strings given their format. The info method shows they are, but the join says different!