# Join values in different dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying trying to join two dataframes in such a way that the resulting union contains info about both of them. My dataframes are similar to:

```
>> df_1
user_id    hashtag1      hashtag2     hashtag3
0000       '#breakfast'  '#lunch'     '#dinner'
0001       '#day'        '#night'     NaN
0002       '#breakfast'  NaN          NaN
```

The second dataframe contains a unique identifier of the hashtags and their respective score:

```
>> df_2
hashtag1       score
'#breakfast'  10
'#lunch'      8
'#dinner'     9
'#day'        -5
'#night'      6
```

I want to add a set of columns on my first dataframe that contain the scores of each `hashtag` used, such as:

```
user_id    hashtag1      hashtag2     hashtag3    score1    score2    score3
0000       '#breakfast'  '#lunch'     '#dinner'   10        8         9
0001       '#day'        '#night'     NaN         -5        6         NaN
0002       '#breakfast'  NaN          NaN         10        NaN       NaN
```

I tried to use `df.join()` but I get an error: "ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

My code is as follows:
`new_df = df_1.join(df_2, how='left', on='hashtag1')`

I appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: I even renamed the column to `hashtag1` in my second dataframe so that `join` may be used on that column, but the error still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `pandas.merge`:

```py
pandas.merge(df_1, df_2, on='hashtag1', how='left')
```

If you want to use `.join`, you need to set the index of `df_2`.

```py
df_1.join(df_2.set_index('hashtag1'), on='hashtag1', how='left')
```

Some resources:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging
- [Trouble with df.join(): ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795399/trouble-with-df-join-valueerror-you-are-trying-to-merge-on-object-and-int64)